# How to send Intent.ACTION_SEND inside BroadcastReceiver's onReceive?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to add an action to my notification, when the user clicks the button, it shares the text of the notification with other apps, here is my code:

```
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val message = intent?.getStringExtra("sharedMessage")
        val shareIntent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            type = "text/plain"
        }
        shareIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        if (context != null) {
            if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
                context.startActivity(shareIntent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `onReceive` function can receive the click action, but it does not start my `shareIntent` which should prompt the user to choose an app for sharing. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are restrictions on background processes (`Service` and `BroadcastReceiver`) launching activities. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

This is probably why you aren't seeing the `Activity` launch.

However, why are you doing this in such a roundabout way? If you want an `Activity` launched when the user clicks on the notification, just do that directly instead of having the notification click start a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I do not know which `activity` installed on the users' device, the `shareIntent` in my code is a implicit intent. I want to share some message without launch my own `activity`. Is it possible?

Comment: I think this should work. Just try it. Put your SHARE `Intent` in the Notification.